# Is there a way to keep/transfer bash environment between subprocess invocations in python?

Tags: python, bash, shell

Problem: suppose I have scripts `A`, `B` and `C1`, `C2`, ... `CN`.

Script `B` sources script `A` which contains  several environment variables and functions, and then calls `C` scripts which rely on them.

Now, let's say I want to replace bash script `B` with a python program.
How would I best do that if I want to "source" `A` exactly once (not before every `C` invocation)?

I want to be able to "process" each C individually, i.e. to run some python code after each C is executed, so creating some big `". A && C1 && C2 ..."` command won't do.

Comment: Maybe you can use `env_parallel` which is part of **GNU Parallel** https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/env_parallel.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this will answer the question as i think it's still unclear in the way you have formulated it but you could use this snippet to parse your bash scripts and run them from python while capturing the output of each line so it might give you a starting point

```
import subprocess

def start_process(command=''):
    return subprocess.Popen(command.split(' '), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=False, 
creationflags = 0x08000000)

with open('yourscript.sh','rt') as f:
    lines = f.read().split('\n')
    output=[str(start_process(line).communicate()[0]) for line in lines]
```

In this way you may be able to architect a structure where your python script coordinates your bash scripts instead of being on equal footing if that makes sense

Comment: Yeah, it looks like you've misunderstood. I don't need to run script line-by-line. I want to run several `Cn` scripts using environment (vars and funcs) set up by `A`.

Basically, that can be achieved by executing `. A && Cn` for each `Cn`, but that's suboptimal and I'd like to know if there is a way to only do something like `. A` once instead of for each script.

Comment: the reason i mentioned this method is because now you can parse the output you're capturing and so if you're querying any environment variables, you can use the values

Answer (score 0):

Short of embedding a `bash` interpreter in your Python program (which is not a realistic option; `bash` wasn't designed to do that), the easiest thing to do is write a wrapper shell script that sources `A`, then uses `exec` to run the Python script. After the `exec`, your Python script keeps the same environment that the wrapper had, including whatever was found in `A`:

```
# wrapper script
source A
exec B.py
```

In `B.py`, each of the `Ci` scripts will then inherit the variables defined in `A` via `B.py`'s environment.

---

Another option is to port `A` into a Python module which `B.py` can import directly. You would change

```
export x=foo
export y=1
```

into

```
import os
os.environ["x"] = "foo"
os.environ["y"] = "1"
```

Depending on how involved `A` really is, porting may not be trivial, which is why I would recommend the wrapper using `exec` first.

Comment: Hm, I'm afraid 1st option wouldn't really work for me, since I need py script to be the "root" of execution and control Cs.

2nd one would work, if not for functions.